# Force menu button in softkeys

Tags: android, softkeys

I developed small sms app. Unfortunately it is not Holo themed. I know that it's 2013 and it should be, but let's just leave it. Recently Google changed API for SMS. I've implemented all needed things and I was forced to change API to 19 (KitKat). With that API 3-dot menu button in softkeys disappeared. Is there option to enable that on 19 API?

Comment: I haven't find an answer for that. I ended "just" redesigning my app

Answer (score 0):

> I was forced to change API to 19 (KitKat)

No. You had use newer SDK to support new API for SMS, but it does not mean you must drop lower versions. Your manifest's `targetSdkVersion` should NOT be 19, but **lowest** supported version. For API specific version you add some `if()` to not execute the code on lower API version. Mind that in such case you must provide code that will work on lower APIs as well. So in your case your new SMS code should be conditional. For APIs lower than 19, old code should still be used.

> With that API 3-dot menu button in softkeys disappeared. Is there option to enable that on 19 API?

Just change your Manifest and rebuild. It's discussed here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't precise enough. My targetSDK is 19, minimumSDK is 7. I have if()s for new changes related to KitKat. Theme.Holo.NoActionBar on Android 4.x doesn't bring menu button back. Or it should and I do something wrong.